# Function only called once from $(function(){

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, web, call

So in my js script I use jQuery, at the top I wrote:

```
$(function() { 
     myFunc(); 
     function myFunc() { 
        console.log("1"); 
     } 
});
```

`"1"` is only printed once which means `myFunc` only ran once, I want it to run every frame/millisecond or basically as fast as it can over and over and over again. Why doesn't it happen like so? If I'm doing it wrong, how can I achieve the effect I want, and what is my mistake?

Comment: What is your use case for doing so? i.e. what problem do you want to solve?

Comment: you can do by while(1){myFunc();} but explain your requirement first

Comment: Learn jQuery : https://www.lynda.com/jQuery-training-tutorials/246-0.html

Comment: I need this inorder to run a function that will adjust the scale/appearance/layout of the website design depending on the window size. So it should always check.

Comment: huh! have you not implemented a responsive design framework like Bootstrap ?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about... I am a huge beginner in the responsive design sphere and really just experimenting, I will look up bootstrap

Comment: If you just need to check for changing window size, try 
`$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        //insert code here
    });`
});

Comment: @xelvis42 - If that is an answer, i urge you to post it as an answer and not as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Vadim Tatarnikov   to call as soon as faster a function in jquery use
>   window.setInterval() with minimum time interval try the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>//add your jquery script file 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
window.setInterval(function(){
 myFunc();
},1);//here i put time interval=1 millisecond
});
function myFunc(){
    console.log("1");
}
```

This will call myFunc() in every 1 millisecond just run and see the console.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `setTimeout()` for execute same function after some interval assume 5 seconds

```
$(function() { 
     myFunc();  // call initially when dom is ready
     function myFunc() { 
        console.log("1"); 
        setTimeout(function(){ myFunc(); }, 5000) // runs after every 5 seconds
     } 
});
```

you can use `setInterval()` as well.

```
$(function() { 
     function myFunc() { 
        console.log("1"); 
     } 
     setInterval(myFunc,0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have written IIFE (immediately invoked function expressions) and the main function runs only once.
You need to call your inner function using setInterval with 0 milliseconds gap.

```
$(function(){ 
     function myFunc(){ 
        console.log("1"); 
     } 
     setInterval(myFunc,0);
});
```

Comment: Will that not cause any crashing etc?

Comment: I believe it won't crash your app. theatrically there is no delay but browser has full control over the callback functions and it knows when to call.
setting interval as 0 will ensure that our call back function will be executed maximum number of times.

try to do minimal calculations with in the callback and return the control as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

your anonymous function (the outer one) runs when the page is loaded.  This places a call to `myFunc` which outputs 1 to the console and then ends.  If you wanted to loop you might try calling `myFunc` at the end of the `myFunc` function, but if you did this you would find that your browser would hang and that eventually you run out of memory.  This is because the call stack would grow and grow, never allowing the UI to respond as javascript is completely in control!

Alternatively, you can use `setTimeout(myFunc, delay)` at the end of your method, which will call it again after a certain amount of milliseconds has passed.  This will not fill the call stack and will allow the UI to respond, but you will have to specify the interval.

A final way is to use 'setInterval(myFunc, delay)' in the place of your outerbody call to 'myFunc()'. This will repeatedly call your function every 'delay' milliseconds forever.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it seems to be clear that you are in dire need to having a Responsive Framework.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.

It removes the need for having/designing separate pages for mobile and desktop.

Just go through the pre-defined bunch of CSS classes and you are set.

No need to write complex logic for window resizing and all that..

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check for changing window size per your comment, try

```
$(function () { 
    $(window).resize(function () { 
        //insert code here 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by:

```
while(1){
  myFunc();
}
```

But explain your requirement first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only runs once (when the page loads).  If you want to run code as fast as your computer can handle, use

```
while(true) {/Your Code here.../}
```

or

```
var interval = setInterval(1, function() {/Your Code Here/});
```

will run the code every 0.001 seconds, and

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

to stop the code from running.  See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a function to run every time you should be placing your function in `setInterval` with interval of `1ms` though its not a recommended way of doing it.

```
$(function(){ 
   setInterval(myFunc,1) 
   function myFunc(){ 
     console.log("1"); 
   } 
});
```

could you please explain your use case for the same,or you could also try to wrap your function call inside a loop.